# ¿Cómo seguir una secuencia de tareas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos buenas tardes me gustaría saber si existe alguna librería de secuencia de tareas para JavaScript, he intentado hacerlo manual pero quería saber si puedo ahorrarme trabajo con alguna librería, les muestro que es lo que necesito.

En la siguiente imagen se muestra una lista de productos con la fecha y hora en la que deben entrar y salir.
Me gustaría llevar una secuencia de productos de inicio y fin, es decir el día y hora que termine el producto 1 en ese momento pueda iniciar el producto 2 con la fecha y hora en la que termino el producto 1 y así sucesivamente.

En el ejemplo podemos ver que el PRODUCTO 1 inicia el 17 de Noviembre del 2021 a las 11:00 PM y termina el 18 de Noviembre a las 5:00 PM, lo que significa que el siguiente producto tendría que iniciar el 18 de Noviembre del 2021 a las 5:00 pm y terminar según sus horas.

[image]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, se los agradecería

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function obtenerDatosTabla(){
    document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = '';

    let horai= document.getElementById("horai").value;
    let nolote= document.getElementById("nolote").value; 



 

    $('#example1 tr').map(function(){
      
    let nombre=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
    let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();
    let maq1=$(this).find('#OSTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq2=$(this).find('#FTHM').eq(0).text();          
    let maq3=$(this).find('#DTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq4=$(this).find('#CFTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq5=$(this).find('#DLTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq6=$(this).find('#LBTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq7=$(this).find('#NTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq8=$(this).find('#RMTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq9=$(this).find('#E1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq10=$(this).find('#E2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq11=$(this).find('#LTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq12=$(this).find('#C2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq13=$(this).find('#C3THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq14=$(this).find('#EKTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq15=$(this).find('#M1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq16=$(this).find('#M2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq17=$(this).find('#CA1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq18=$(this).find('#CA2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq19=$(this).find('#EFTHM').eq(0).text(); 
  
    //aqui sumo los dias y las horas

    const sec1 = moment(horai).add(maq1, 'hours').format('LLL');
    const sec2 = moment(sec1).add(maq2, 'hours').format('LLL');
    const sec3 = moment(sec2).add(maq3, 'hours').format('LLL');

         
    var multi=(2*maq1);
    var F1=multi+parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
    parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
    parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18);
    var multi2=(2*maq19);
    var F2=parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
    parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
    parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18)+multi2;

    var M1= "Máquina 1";
   var M2= "Máquina 2"
    
    function Maquina1(nombre,F1,M1,nolote,horai,sec1,sec2,sec3){
      this.nombre=nombre;
      this.F1=F1;
      this.M1=M1; 
      this.nolote=nolote; 
      this.horai=horai; 
      this.sec1=sec1; 
      this.sec2=sec2; 
      this.sec3=sec3; 
          }

function Maquina2(nombre,F2,M2,nolote,horai,sec1,sec2,sec3){
      this.nombre=nombre;
      this.F2=F2;
      this.M2=M2; 
      this.nolote=nolote; 
      this.horai=horai;
      this.sec1=sec1; 
      this.sec2=sec2; 
      this.sec3=sec3; 
}    
if(F1<=F2){
for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
secuencias= new secuencias(horai,sec1,sec2,sec3);
ORDER= new Maquina1(nombre,F1, M1,nolote,horai,sec1,sec2,sec3);
agregar();
}
}

    });
    
    }
    var basedeDatos=[];
    function agregar(){
      var cadena = '';
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = cadena;
      basedeDatos.push(ORDER);
      var data =_.orderBy (basedeDatos,[ 'M1','F1' ] ,  [ 'asc','asc']);  
      for (var j = 1; j <=19; j++) { 
      data.forEach(maquina => {

          cadena += '<tr>'
          cadena += '<td>' + [j] + '</td>'
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.nombre + '</td>'
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.nolote + '</td>'
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.horai+ '</td>'
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.sec1 + '</td>'
          cadena += '</tr>'
          
        })
      } 

  document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = cadena;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: y el código????

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo agregué

Comment: Buen día,  en si que es lo que intentas realizar, ya que creo no es muy claro,  vas a tener tu pagina abierta siempre, quieres modificar cuando cargue, o desde donde vas a mantener ese estado de tu producto